# How to randomly pick an item in a list excluding one possiblity?

Tags: python, list

What is the easiest way to randomly pick an item from a list with the exception of a given item in the list?

Example:
`list = [2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 34, 54,]`

How do I randomly pick any number except 7?

Comment: ```import random; random.choice([x for x in list if x not in [7,]])```

Comment: Remove it from the list first, or take a random number from the list and try again when you get 7.

Comment: Write a loop that randomly picks a item from the list until it gets one not equal to the exclude value. Could make a function out of it if there's a need to do it more than once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two main strategies are possible:

Remove the exception from the list, and sample from that:

```
import random

def choice_excluding(lst, exception):
    possible_choices = [v for v in lst if v != exception]
    return random.choice(possible_choices)
```

Or just take a random choice from your complete list, and try again as long a you get the forbidden value (rejection sampling):

```
def reject_sample(lst, exception):
    while True:
        choice = random.choice(lst)
        if choice != exception:
            return choice
```

Both will get the same results (well, as long as same goes for random...):

```
lst = [2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 34, 54]
choice_excluding(lst, 7)
# 9
reject_sample(lst, 7)
# 54
```

Depending on the size of your list, one may be faster than the other. Try and see!

Comment: The `reject_sample` method will enter an infinite loop if the list `lst` contains `exception` and *only* it.