# Randomly Replacing Characters in String with Character Other than the Current Character

Tags: python, string, random

Suppose that I have a string that I would like to modify at random with a defined set of options from another string. First, I created my original string and the potential replacement characters:

```
string1 = "abcabcabc"
replacement_chars = "abc"
```

Then I found this function on a forum that will randomly replace *n* characters:

```
def randomlyChangeNChar(word, value):
     length = len(word)
     word = list(word)
     # This will select the distinct index for us to replace
     k = random.sample(range(0, length), value) 
     for index in k:
         # This will replace the characters at the specified index with the generated characters
         word[index] = random.choice(replacement_chars)
# Finally print the string in the modified format.
return "".join(word)
```

This code does what I want with one exception -- it does not account for characters in string1 that match the random replacement character. I understand that the problem is in the function that I am trying to adapt, I predict under the `for` loop, but I am unsure what to add to prevent the substituting character from equaling the old character from string1. All advice appreciated, if I'm overcomplicating things please educate me!

Comment: Why don't you repeat drawing a random character until you have drawn one that is different from the one that it is going to replace, and only then replace it?

Comment: I considered this option as well but also couldn't figure out this method. Although, admittedly, I didn't pursue this option very far because the data I am working with can be extremely large; it would be computationally expensive to do this with the length of strings I am working with.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's true or if any other method will be better.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Agreed, I'm not sure if another method would be better, but the strings I'm working with could theoretically be millions of characters long if I wanted to apply this method (field is computational biology).

Comment: @OneMadGypsy My expected output is a modified string at random character indices, with any character that is replaced not being the original character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomly pick an item in a list excluding one possiblity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933529/how-to-randomly-pick-an-item-in-a-list-excluding-one-possiblity)

Comment: @Swifty Thanks for the input! Trying out those methods now. Also looking at the post mkrieger1 just posted and it looks promising as well.

Comment: @Swifty Your second solution works perfectly! Can you please make a short post explaining your methodology and why it works the way that it does so I can understand better?

Comment: After looking at the post @mkrieger1 linked, there indeed seems to be 2 approached: redraw until you get what you want, or first exclude the exception from the choices. I have a strong feeling the 2nd approach is more efficient; that's the one I chose in my answer.

Comment: Can I suggest that your question could dispense with everything following the second code block (the function you're trying to adapt), and just close with "how do I ensure every replacement is different from the character it is replacing?" This would "tighten" up the question considerably. Thanks

Comment: @Vin Agreed,  but was unsure how much context was needed originally. Approved your edit!

Thank you again everyone who has contributed to this thread!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function you retrieved, replacing:

```
word[index] = random.choice(replacement_chars)
```

with

```
word[index] = random.choice(replacement_chars.replace(word[index],'')
```

will do the job. It simply replaces word[index] (the char you want to replace) with an empty string in the replacement_chars string, effectively removing it from the replacement characters.

Another approach, that will predictably be less efficient on average, is to redraw until you get a different character from the original one:

that is, replacing:

```
word[index] = random.choice(replacement_chars)
```

with

```
char = word[index]
while char == word[index]:
    char = random.choice(replacement_chars)
word[index] = char
```

or

```
while True:
    char = random.choice(replacement_chars)
    if char != word[index]:
        word[index] = char
        break
```

WARNING: if replacement_chars only features 1 character, both methods would fail when the original character is the same as the replacement one!

Comment: The first approach you suggest is palpably superior  - and SO elegant :).  Two edge cases where it might fail - `replacement_chars` might have only one character, and replacement chars might have duplicate characters. the latter case at least could be accommodated with `replacement_chars = ''.join(list(set(replacement_chars)))` or similar. The former case would require bespoke treatment depending on OP's preferred/program logic. Your latter solution, involving a `while` loop runs the risk of never breaking...

Comment: Indeed; though in case of repeated chars in replacement_chars, it could be a deliberate choice (to tune the odds of different chars), so turning it to a set would lose that. I added a warning at the end of my answer.

Comment: And anyway, your 2nd edge case isn't problematic, since .replace() replaces ALL occurrences of the substring.